# ExecShellResult doesn't like my pipes

Tags: linux, awk, grep, cut, cfengine

I wrote the following `ExecShellResult` fragment in cfengine v2.2.1a:

```
control:
    active_interface_mac = ( ExecShellResult(/sbin/ifconfig ${active_interface} | /usr/bin/grep 'ether ' | /usr/bin/cut -f2 -d' ') )
    ...
    time_drift = ( ExecShellResult(/usr/sbin/ntpdate -d pool.ntp.org 2>/dev/null | /usr/bin/grep -o 'offset.*sec' | /usr/bin/cut -f2 -d' ') )
    ...
shellcommands:
    "/bin/echo ${time_drift}" inform=true syslog=true
```

When running the above from the command line, it obviously works fine:

```
$ ntpdate ...
0.183693
```

However, if run inside cfengine, I get a syntax error:

```
$ cfagent -qIK
Executing script /bin/echo /usr/bin/cut...(timeout=0,uid=-1,gid=-1)
cfengine:/bin/echo /usr/: /usr/bin/cut
cfengine: Finished script /bin/echo /usr/bin/cut
cfengine: 
Executing script /bin/echo  option requires an argument -- d usage...(timeout=0,uid=-1,gid=-1)
cfengine:/bin/echo  opti: option requires an argument -- d usage
cfengine: Finished script /bin/echo  option requires an argument -- d usage
cfengine: 
Executing script /bin/echo  cut -b list [-n] [file ...]        cut -c list [file ...]        cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]...(timeout=0,uid=-1,gid=-1)
cfengine:/bin/echo  cut : cut -b list [-n] [file ...] cut -c list [file ...] cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]
cfengine: Finished script /bin/echo  cut -b list [-n] [file ...]        cut -c list [file ...]        cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]
```

Note the error is being displayed when we run the `echo` command under `shellcommands:`. By then, the `${time_drift}` variable has been already evaluated, and its result shows we invoke `cut`'s `-d` option incorrectly, complaining that we didn't pass anything to `-d` which is obviously not true.

This is baffling, because `${active_interface_mac}` uses the same syntax and works perfectly.

I tried replacing the second grep with `| tail -1 | sed 's///'`, another `grep -o [0-9]*.[0-9]` or anything else I could think of, including `/usr/bin/cut -f1 -d'${spc}'`. I apparently can't use `awk` because cfengine interprets `$(NF)` as parentheses which are part of `ExecShellResult`, even when escaped.

What other options do I have to get my actual seconds value extracted from `ntpdate`'s output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure about cfengine 2, I don't see what would trip it up in your example
but for cfengine 3:

```
bundle agent main
{
  vars:

    "ntpdate_s"
      string => execresult( "/usr/sbin/ntpdate -d pool.ntp.org 2> /dev/null | /usr/bin/awk '/offset .* sec/ {print $10}'", useshell ),
      if => not( isvariable( offset ) );

  reports:
    "Mac address of wlan0 $(sys.hardware_mac[wlan0])";
    "Offset is $(ntpdate_s)";
}
```

Output:

```
R: Mac address of wlan0 5c:e0:c5:9f:f3:8f
R: Offset is 0.027672
```